# How can I make my horizontal scroll view in Kivy centered on the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to make a horizontal scroll view in Kivy (Python) which would display an image (buttons for now) that you can scroll through. I've been able to figure out how to do the horizontal scroll view, but I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong to center on the screen. Here is what I have so far:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        self.spacing=50
        self.size_hint=(None, .5)
        self.bind(minimum_width=self.setter('width'))

class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        scroll = ScrollView( size_hint=(1,1), do_scroll_x=True, do_scroll_y=False )
        grid = MyGrid()
        for i in range(60):
            grid.add_widget(Button(text='#00' + str(i),size=(100,100), size_hint=(1,1)))
        scroll.add_widget(grid)
        return scroll

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

I looked through the documentation and I think it has something to do with pos_hint: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=pos_hint#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint

I tried adding:

```
self.pos={'center_y':1}
```

in my MyGrid() class, but nothing is being changed. No matter what value is I put after center_y, my the ScrollView contained in the grid still appears at the top of the screen, rather than centered halfway down. I've also tried adjusting things in the ScrollViewApp() class too, using

```
scroll.pos={'center_y':1}
```

as well. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm not understanding here? I feel like I'm so close!!!

**Edit:**

I'm trying to have the buttons centered, but also be able to scroll by dragging the black space around the buttons. In the picture below, you can see there is a bunch of black space beneath the buttons. I can click a button or this black space and scroll horizontally. I just need this to happen with the buttons centered!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layout is behaving as you told it to.
You have a `ScrollView` as a root widget, and inside it you put your `Grid` that has `size_hint_y = 0.5`.

It takes half of the parent widget height, that takes the full window height.
One way to center your `Grid` is to put some spacers over and under it, but this is not possible, since `ScrollView` accepts onle one widget as content.

So, one solution is to..

- let the `Grid` have the full height of the `ScrollView`
- add the `ScrollView` inside another Layout (e.g. a `BoxLayout`)
- and finally, add two widgets to force the `ScrollView` in the center.

```py
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        self.spacing = 50
        self.size_hint = (None, 1)
        self.bind(minimum_width=self.setter('width'))


class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        base = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint=(1, 1))
        base.add_widget(Widget(size_hint_y=.3))
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, .4), do_scroll_x=True, do_scroll_y=False)
        grid = MyGrid()
        for i in range(60):
            grid.add_widget(
                Button(text='#00' + str(i), size=(100, 100), size_hint=(1, 1)))
        scroll.add_widget(grid)
        base.add_widget(scroll)
        base.add_widget(Widget(size_hint_y=.3))
        return base


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Another approach would be to..

- put the `ScrollView` inside a `FloatLayout`
- and position it using `pos_hint`

```py
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        # self.spacing = 50
        self.size_hint = (None, 1)
        self.bind(minimum_width=self.setter('width'))


class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        base = FloatLayout(size_hint=(1, 1))
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, .4), do_scroll_x=True, do_scroll_y=False,
                            pos_hint={"center_y": .5})
        grid = MyGrid()
        for i in range(60):
            grid.add_widget(
                Button(text='#00' + str(i), width=100, size_hint=(None, 1)))
        scroll.add_widget(grid)
        base.add_widget(scroll)
        return base


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

**Edit:**

OK. After the update of the question, this is a way to to center and use the black bars to scroll:

```py
Builder.load_string("""
<BaseWidget>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y: False
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.minimum_width
            Widget:
                size_hint_y: .3
            GridLayout:
                id: grid
                rows: 1
                size_hint_y: .4
                size_hint_x: None
                width: self.minimum_width
            Widget:
                size_hint_y: .3
""")


class BaseWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass


class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        base = BaseWidget()
        for i in range(60):
            base.ids.grid.add_widget(Button(text='#00' + str(i),
                                            width=100, size_hint_x=None))
        return base


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

It uses `kv_lng` to create the layout because I find it easier to the eye.
For a "Python only" code you can use this:

```py
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        self.size_hint = None, .4
        self.bind(minimum_width=self.setter('width'))


class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.size_hint_x = None
        self.bind(minimum_width=self.setter('width'))


class ScrollViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        base = FloatLayout()
        grid = MyGrid()
        box = MyBox()
        box.add_widget(Widget(size_hint_y=.3))
        box.add_widget(grid)
        box.add_widget(Widget(size_hint_y=.3))
        for i in range(60):
            grid.add_widget(Button(text='#00' + str(i), width=100, size_hint_x=None))
        scroll = ScrollView(do_scroll_y=False, pos_hint={"center_y": .5})
        scroll.add_widget(box)
        base.add_widget(scroll)
        return base


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Your examples do indeed center the buttons, but I can't use the black space around the buttons to scroll horizontally. How could I tweak your second example to accomplish this? Sorry, even though you answered my question, I didn't adequately communicate my requirement in my original post! I have edited my original question to reflect this need.

Comment: Thank you SO much, @noEmbryo! Your code was the answer I am looking for. I was also able to learn a bit more about how to use Kivy as well. Thanks again!